# How to replace text in the beginning of the line using sed?

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I'm trying to run a sed script in which the following line isn't working.

from sedfile.sed file:

```
s|^NEWLINE|XYZ|g
```

I'm unable to figure it out but why?

I am on windows and I am running it using a batch file.

Command is being issued as: `preprocess_answers.bat temp.text`

contents of `preprocess_answers.bat`

```
:preserving newline characters
fart -C %1 \r\n NEWLINE
sed -i -E -f preprocess_answers.sed %1
```

contents of `preprocess_answers.sed`

```
#usage: sed -i -E -f preprocess_answers.sed  filename.tex
s|(NEWLINE *[0-9]+\. *)|\n\1|g
s|Hint|\tHint|g
#s|^NEWLINE([^\r\n\t]+)|\\begin{finalanswer} \1 \\end{finalanswer}|g
s|^NEWLINE|XYZ|g
s|\t(Hint[^\r\n]+)|\t\\begin{hint} \1 \\end{hint}|g
```

contents of `temp.text`

```
1. (b)
2. (c)
3. (c)
4. (a)
5. (b)
1. asdf Hint: asdfasdf
1. asdf Hint: asdfasdf
1. asdf Hint: asdfasdf
1. asdf Hint: asdfasdf
1. asdf Hint: asdfasdf
```

after runing the command, the text file looks like this:

```
1. (b)
NEWLINE2. (c)
NEWLINE3. (c)
NEWLINE4. (a)
NEWLINE5. (b)
NEWLINE1. asdf      \begin{hint} Hint: asdfasdf \end{hint}
NEWLINE1. asdf      \begin{hint} Hint: asdfasdf \end{hint}
NEWLINE1. asdf      \begin{hint} Hint: asdfasdf \end{hint}
NEWLINE1. asdf      \begin{hint} Hint: asdfasdf \end{hint}
NEWLINE1. asdf      \begin{hint} Hint: asdfasdf \end{hint}
```

**EDIT:**

I am trying to get the commented out line: `s|^NEWLINE([^\r\n\t]+)|\\begin{finalanswer} \1 \\end{finalanswer}|g` to work, but since it was failing, in the process of debugging, I found that `^` is the culprit.

Comment: Does `sed -f sedfile.sed temp.txt` work?

Comment: @anubhava: yes, if I remove `^` from  infront of `NEWLINE` the script works fine.

Comment: make sure you don't have any leading spaces in the lines of `temp.txt`. Also, no need for the -E flag, as the `^` metacharacter is part of the default BRE (Basic Regular Expression).

Comment: Also, you can add `sedfile.sed`. Maybe some other commands affect your failed command (as sed will execute all commands on each line).

Comment: I edited and pasted "exactly" what I am doing.

Comment: Scare quotes around _exactly_ imply to English speakers that you actually didn't.

Comment: @tripleee: oh! I didn't know that. I thought I was emphasizing the fact that I pasted it exactly. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is a stream editor, and it loads each line of the stream into the pattern space, then executes *all the commands in your `.sed` file*, **then** loads the next line, etc.

Except you have removed all linebreaks and replaced them with 'NEWLINE'.  So you are loading everything into the pattern space and processing everything at once.  (You can do with with `sed -z`, or with `$!N;${...your commands}`, or with branching.)

In any event, `^` matches the beginning of the pattern space, not the beginning of every line.  I'd recommend using `\b` to mean 'word boundary' because it's zero-space.  ie: `\bNEWLINE`

You also ought to see whether `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` exist on your system to deal with the whole DOS linebreak thing.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That makes lot of sense now. I have lost touch with using these tools. 

If you don't mind, can you please show me how the repacement using `sed - z` work?

Comment: `sed -z` is a GNU sed thing, might not be available on your install.  But it would be as simple as `sed -z 's/\r\n/\nNEWLINE/g` dosfile`  to get NEWLINE at the beginning of each line.   And don't be afraid to pipe sed to sed if you're trying to do a simple manipulation with `sed -z` followed by line-by-line sed.